# R - Finding rows with repeated elements

Tags: r, regex, string

I'm having some trouble making a regex that'll match rows with repeated elements...

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

`View (df)`

| ID | Sequence |
| --- | --- |
| ID_1 | ATCGATTTCGAGGGCGTACG |
| ID_2 | ATGCAGTAGCCCCATCGAGT |
| ID_3 | ACGTAAAACGTCGAGAGAGT |
| ID_4 | GAAGATCGTCGTCGTCGTCG |
| ID_5 | ACTGTAGCTCGAAAGGGCCC |

I'm trying to find the row that constains an element that is repeated consecutively at least 5 times. In this example, then, it would be row 4, since the desired element TCG is repeated consecutively 5 times.

But when I do:

`which (grepl (x = df$Sequence, pattern = "TCG{5, }"))`

It returns all 5 rows, because all of them contain TCG repeated once somewhere inside the string.

I'm trying to learn more about regex, but I'd GREATLY appreciate any help right now!!!

Comment: You could do `pattern = "T{5}|C{5}|G{5}"`

Comment: Are elements always 3 letters?

Comment: Yes! They're always a three-letter element

Comment: I tried Andrew's suggestion but, sadly, it didn't work 

Comment: `"(TCG){5,}"` <- look for capture group "TCG" exactly, repeat the group 5 or more times.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh!!! Thanks, Paul !!!! It seemed to have worked!!! I'm so happy, thank youuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 3):

You can use `()` to group `TCG`

```
> with(df,grep("(TCG){5,}", Sequence))
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr` and `grepl`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = "
  ID    Sequence
  ID_1  ATCGATTTCGAGGGCGTACG
  ID_2  ATGCAGTAGCCCCATCGAGT
  ID_3  ACGTAAAACGTCGAGAGAGT
  ID_4  GAAGATCGTCGTCGTCGTCG
  ID_5  ACTGTAGCTCGAAAGGGCCC
                 ", header =T)


df |> filter(grepl('(TCG){5}', Sequence))
#>     ID             Sequence
#> 1 ID_4 GAAGATCGTCGTCGTCGTCG
```